# HAML: how to use multi line with element that has a lot of classes?

Tags: haml

How to split this line?

```
%a.class-1.class-2.class-3.class-4.class-5.class-6.class-7.class-8.class-9.class-10
```

Is there a way to do it like this?

```
%a.class-1
          .class-2.class-3.class-4
          .class-5.class-6.class-7
          .class-8.class-9.class-10
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your syntax to use [a class attribute](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#attributes_), being careful to keep the same indentation after each comma:

```
%a{ class: ['class-1',
            'class-2',
            'class-3',
            'class-4',
            'class-5',
            'class-6',
            'class-7',
            'class-8',
            'class-9',
            'class-10'] }
```

Comment: Your first solution is obvious, and it seems to be the only option.
Backslashes are used for escaping http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#escaping_
and your second example will render hyperlink with many divs. Can you update your answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @SlavaNikulin Escaping isn't the only thing backslashes are used for.  Let me edit my answer with the example code I used, and see if you get the same output.

Comment: When you run `puts haml` before render, you will see, that all characters from the second example are in single line `"%a.class-1.class-2.class-3.class-4.class-5.class-6.class-7.class-8.class-9.class-10"`.
This won't work when you use haml file. Try https://www.haml-converter.com/

Comment: @SlavaNikulin interesting, thanks for that!  Well, I'll modify my answer then to remove the backslash option.